# Загрузка фото с сервера с Laravel/Sanctum

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, auth, media-library, sanctum

Есть Back api на laravel и фронт nuxt.js. Вопрос как загрузить img в компоненте если фото находится в защищённых путях laravel sanctum. Пробовал запускать через axios=>vuex=>img src, но ничего не выводит. На сервере для хранения юзается Laravel-medialibrary. Был бы рад любым вариантам решения этой задачи.

Comment: А что конкретно не получается? Приведите фрагмен не работающего кода. Так же не понятна фраза: `защищённых путях laravel sanctum`. Тоже бы код увидеть: `Пробовал запускать через axios=>vuex=>img src, но ничего не выводит`.